# How to add a Mapbox layer using R, Shiny, and Mapboxer?

Tags: r, shiny, leaflet, mapbox

I have an Shiny application using [Leaflet](https://leafletjs.com). I will migrate it to [Mapbox](https://www.mapbox.com) using [mapboxer](https://github.com/crazycapivara/mapboxer) library.

My main question is how to adapt the scenario below:

1. The user can choose the data which will be displayed on the map by selecting a column of the DATA dataframe (add_fill_layer)
2. By selecting a region the map will fit that area (fit_bounds)
3. Get event when the map is `clicked` on a region and/or `on mouse hover`

Find below a reproducible example

**global.R**

```
library(dplyr)
library(shiny)
library(leaflet)
library(mapboxer)
library(purrr)
library(sf)

MAPBOX_TOKEN <- "THIS_HAVE_TO_BE_A_VALID_MAPBOX_TOKEN"

MELBOURNE_MAP <- sf::st_read(geojsonsf::geo_melbourne)

places <- as.data.frame(MELBOURNE_MAP) %>% select(SA2_NAME) %>% pull() %>% append("All regions", 0)

places_length <- length(places)

Names <- as.vector(places[2 : places_length])
ColA <- as.vector(sample(1 : 100, size = places_length - 1, replace = TRUE))
ColB <- as.vector(sample(1 : 100, size = places_length - 1, replace = TRUE))

MELBOURNE_DATA <- data.frame(Names = Names, ColA = ColA, ColB = ColB)
```

**ui.R**

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  selectInput("Region", label = "Region", choices = places),
  selectInput("Column", label = "Column", choices = c("ColA", "ColB")),
  h1("Leaflet Map"),
  uiOutput("clicked_leaflet_region"),
  leafletOutput("leafletMap", width = "50%"),
  h1("Mapbox Map"),
  uiOutput("clicked_mapbox_region"),
  mapboxerOutput("mapboxMap", width = "50%"),
)
```

**server.R**

```
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  bbox <- reactive ({
    st_bbox(MELBOURNE_MAP$geometry) %>% as.vector()
  })
  
  output$leafletMap <- renderLeaflet({
    leaflet(options = leafletOptions(minZoom = 10, maxZoom = 200, zoomControl = TRUE, zoomSnap = 0.5)) %>%
      addProviderTiles("Esri.WorldGrayCanvas") %>%
      fitBounds(bbox()[1], bbox()[2], bbox()[3], bbox()[4])
  })
  
  output$mapboxMap <- renderMapboxer({
    mapboxer(style = "mapbox://styles/mapbox/light-v11", token = MAPBOX_TOKEN) %>%
      fit_bounds(bbox())
  })
  
  data_to_show <- eventReactive(input$Column, {
    MELBOURNE_DATA %>% select(Name, get(input$Column))
  })
  
  update_leafletMap <- function(column, region=NULL) {
    pal <- colorBin(c("#EDF8E9", "#C7E9C0", "#A1D99B", "#74C476", "#31A354", "#006D2C"),
                    domain = c(1: 100),
                    bins = c(0, 25, 50, 100))
    
    pallete <- pal(MELBOURNE_DATA[[column]])
    
    hlopts <- highlightOptions(
      weight = 5,
      color = "#666666",
      fillOpacity = 0.7)
    
    p <- leafletProxy("leafletMap")
    
    p <- p %>% clearShapes() %>% clearControls()
    
    p <- p %>% addPolygons(data = MELBOURNE_MAP,
                           weight = 1,
                           color = "white",
                           smoothFactor = 0.5,
                           fillOpacity = 0.8,
                           fillColor = pallete,
                           highlight = hlopts,
                           group = "By Name",
                           layerId = MELBOURNE_MAP$SA2_NAME)
    
    if (region == "All regions") {
      p <- p %>% fitBounds(bbox()[1], bbox()[2], bbox()[3], bbox()[4])
    } else {
      l <- MELBOURNE_MAP %>% filter(SA2_NAME == region) %>% select(geometry)
      bbox <- st_bbox(l$geometry) %>% as.vector()
      p <- p %>% fitBounds(bbox[1], bbox[2], bbox[3], bbox[4])
    }    
    p
  }
  
  update_mapboxMap <- function(column, region) {
    p <- mapboxer_proxy("mapboxMap")
    p <- p %>% add_fill_layer()   # What to do here??? Please, see note 1 above.

    if (region == "All regions") {
      p <- p %>% fit_bounds(bbox())
    } else {
      l <- MELBOURNE_MAP %>% filter(SA2_NAME == region) %>% select(geometry)
      bbox <- st_bbox(l$geometry) %>% as.vector()
      p <- p %>% fit_bounds(bbox)  # This is not working!!! Please, see note 2 above
    }    
    p
  }
  
  observeEvent(c(input$Region, input$Column), {
    update_leafletMap(input$Column, input$Region)
    update_mapboxMap(input$Column, input$Region)
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$leafletMap_shape_click, {
    event <- input$leafletMap_shape_click
    output$clicked_leaflet_region <- renderUI({ HTML(paste0("<h2>",event$id,"</h2>")) })
  })
}
```

This simple example works as expected when using Leaflet, but not for Mapbox.

Please, by commenting below, let me know if any other information is necessary for helping answering this issue.

I tried to feed `add_fill_layer` with `as_mapbox_source` method by using MELBOURNE_MAP, MELBOURNE_DATA, and merging them.

**Updated on Dec 3rd, 2022**

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to to call the update function `update_mapboxer` in the end.
Usually you won't call the `add_layer` function but only update the data with `set_data`. See [this example](https://github.com/crazycapivara/mapboxer/blob/master/examples/shiny-set-data.R).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unlikely, this doesn't apply for the case. I updated the post with two images for exemplify what I am trying to do with `mapboxer`

Comment: Hi, I am back to this and I finally understand your point. It totally makes sense. So, marking it as the solution.